# What should i do with setup directory in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

my magento version is 2.1.7
and i noticed that there a directory called setup when i go tho this directory via web like exmaple. com/setup i got this message

> Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. 
>   To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard

---

should i delete this folder ?
or how can i disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

The webroot in production should be `install_root/pub` instead of `install_root` that removes access to `setup` and all other application code directories.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete this folder. It is important for install components, modules, and extensions, upgrade your installation, and change the system configuration.

check web wizard  go to Magento backend. `System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard`

[image]

**For reference :**

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/web-setup-wizard.html